# Extracting internal forces of cloth simulation springs for manipulation in Python script

Tags: python, cloth-simulation, bmesh

Is it possible to extract the simulated forces per-frame per-vertex in the 4 springs as described here [Link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/cloth/introduction.html#springs)?

I have come across this [Mesh Tension Tool](https://github.com/chiragraman/mesh-tension) which infers strain(tension) through mesh deformation(new_edge_len/pristine_edge_len), but preferably would be better to access the numeric data in the simulated spring directly.

I have dug around the Blender API (BMesh in particular [Here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#mesh-elements)), but not sure if the data is stored with mesh data/exposed by the API. The cloth simulation setting ([Here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ClothSettings.html?highlight=cloth#bpy.types.ClothSettings)) variables appear to be as described, settings only. Given that we can define the maximum of these forces ([Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/cloth/settings/property_weights.html)), I assume that there will be some way to access these values per-frame per-vertex, rather than just user defined settings?

Would there be any possibility of getting in touch with the cloth simulation authors regarding the feasibility of this?

Thank you!